# Terraform setup of postgres conf files (pg_hba_conf + postgresql.conf) via User Data on AWS ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql, terraform

I am setting up a cheap postgres server on amazon ec2, using Terraform.

I know I can add a User Data file when setting up a ec2 instance.
I know that with terraform, I can provide that User Data script file, using the `file(..)` function. So far so good.

My problem is I would like to also automate the final steps of pg setup, i.e. modifying the `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` files during that same user data script's execution. Is that possible?

I.e. If I create a `pghbaconftpl.conf` file alongside my other terraform files, can I do `cat pghbaconftpl.conf > /correct/path/to/pg_hba.conf` in the ec2 User Data script and expect it to work? I don't see how that would work. :-/

In general is it possible to inject other script files that can be launch from user data script? If so, how?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can use the [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) function to create a template of the required file. Alternatively, you can use the remote-exec to run whatever you want on the remote file https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/remote-exec

the two approaches will depend on what exactly you're trying to do

Comment: @SathyajithBhat omg... thank you! I didn't know about remote-exec at all! Yes between `templatefile()` and `remote-exec`, I think I can get what I need. TY!! If you feel like putting your comment in an answer, will be happy to accept.

Comment: done, answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) function to create a template of the required file.

Alternatively, you can use the remote-exec to run whatever you want on the remote file

> The remote-exec provisioner invokes a script on a remote resource after it is created. This can be used to run a configuration management tool, bootstrap into a cluster, etc. To invoke a local process, see the local-exec provisioner instead. The remote-exec provisioner requires a connection and supports both ssh and winrm.

So you could do

```
... 
 provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
       "cat pghbaconftpl.conf > /correct/path/to/pg_hba.conf"
    ]
  }
```

or whatever else you want to run on the remote instance. You can point to a shell script, copy a file from your terraform repo, template it to a location on the remote instance and run it.

The two approaches will depend on what exactly you're trying to do.